# Filesort fixed/added when adding/removing 2 bits of code

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, query-optimization

```
SELECT test2.*, account.*
FROM test2
     JOIN account on test2.account_id = account.id
where test2.id > 0
and test2.active = TRUE
and account.age BETWEEN 18 AND 80 AND account.gender = 'MALE'
ORDER BY test2.id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER',
  `bio` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_profile_pic_uuid` char(32) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture_verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `looking_for` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `include_in_search` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_active` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_username_uindex` (`username`),
  KEY `account_email_index` (`email`),
  KEY `account_location_id_fk` (`location_id`),
  KEY `account_multi_index` (`include_in_search`,`location_id`,`gender`,`looking_for`,`age`,`picture_verified`),
  KEY `account_multi2_index` (`include_in_search`,`looking_for`,`age`,`location_id`,`gender`,`picture_verified`),
  KEY `account_multi3_index` (`include_in_search`,`looking_for`,`age`,`gender`,`picture_verified`,`location_id`),
  KEY `account_available_for_chat_index` (`available_for_chat`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_location_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=710538 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
  `began` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ending` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test2_active_ending_index` (`active`,`ending`),
  KEY `test2_account_id_fk` (`account_id`,`id` DESC),
  CONSTRAINT `test2_account_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1002031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

To the point, test2 has about 1mil rows AFTER the filtering, account has about 700k also after filtering.

The above works in about 2sec with `filesort`, way too slow:

```
1   SIMPLE  account     ALL PRIMARY             702300  1.11    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  test2       ref PRIMARY,test2_active_ending_index,test2_account_id_fk   test2_account_id_fk 4   db.account.id   2   25  Using index condition; Using where
```

If I take out the "and account.age BETWEEN 18 AND 80 AND account.gender = 'MALE'" bit BUT keep ***"ORDER BY test2.id DESC"***, works in 10ms, no `filesort`.

If I take out the ***"ORDER BY test2.id DESC"*** bit BUT keep ***""and account.age BETWEEN 18 AND 80 AND account.gender = 'MALE'"***, works in 10ms, no `filesort`.
No order by:

```
1   SIMPLE  account     ALL PRIMARY             702300  1.11    Using where
1   SIMPLE  test2       ref PRIMARY,test2_active_ending_index,test2_account_id_fk   test2_account_id_fk 4   db.account.id   2   25  Using index condition; Using where
```

All of the fields have either individual or compound indexes.

Anyone know how to get the execution time lower or get rid of the `filesort`?

I have another unrelated table to this, that's very similar in design to test2, with 1 mil rows, and when i run the exact same query on it it completes very fast:

```
1   SIMPLE  new_table       range   PRIMARY,new_table_account_id_fk PRIMARY 4       498496  100 Using where; Backward index scan
1   SIMPLE  account     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.new_table.account_id 1   5   Using where
```

Notice the difference under type & ref & extra, compared to test2. I tried limiting the number of account rows for test2 to under 300k, same speed and result.

Comment: Why `where test2.id > 0`?  Do you have some rows <= 0 in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column??  I ask because the test gets in the way of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

First some general statements:

- Filtering on two tables (`WHERE` clause hits two tables) leads the Optimizer to guess which table to start with.  Sometimes the solution is to move columns used for filtering into a single table.  This may not apply in your case.
- When using `LIMIT`, it is often better to fetch the ids for the limited number of rows, then reach back into the table(s) to get the rest of the columns.
- Don't use `SELECT *` unless you really need all the columns.  Large (`TEXT`/`BLOB`) columns may be extra costly to fetch, only to later be thrown away.
- Unless you are using MySQL 8.0, don't mix directions, as in `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC.  Sometimes it is 'good enough' to change both to the same direction.
- Unless you are doing something strange with the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, the value will always be `> 0`.

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  test2.*,
        account.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  test2.id AS t_id, account.id AS a_id
            FROM  test2
            JOIN  account  ON test2.account_id = account.id
            WHERE  test2.active = TRUE
              AND  EXISTS (
                SELECT  1
                    FROM  account
                    WHERE  age BETWEEN 18 AND 80
                      AND  gender = 'MALE'
                      AND  id = test2.account_id 
                          )
            ORDER BY  test2.id
            LIMIT  20 
         ) AS x
    JOIN  test2    ON test2.id   = x.t_id
    JOIN  account  ON account.id = x.a_id
    ORDER BY  test2.id -- Yes, repeated
```

With this composite index:

```
test2:  (active, id, account_id)  -- in this order (covering)
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any formulations that you want to discuss.